# What's Wrong with my Merge sort Code?

Tags: c#, algorithm, mergesort

I am learning to code and I though I'd try writing a merge sort algorithm (something we heard about in our analytic course but NOT homework). I was working from the pseudo code the trainer showed us but I cannot identify the problem. Any chance someone could point me in the right direction?

edit: The algorithm only returns the first value in the List.

```
static List<int> mergeSort(List<int> mj)
{
    List<int>m = mj;
    if(m.Count <= 1)
        return m;
    List<int> merge = new List<int>();

    List<int> left = new List<int>();
    List<int> right = new List<int>();
    int middle = m.Count/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
        left.Add(m[i]);
    for (int j = middle; j >= m.Count; j++)
        right.Add(m[j]);

    left = mergeSort(left);
    right = mergeSort(right);

    merge.AddRange(left);
    merge.AddRange(right);

    for (int k = 0; k < merge.Count; k++)
    {
        Console.Write(merge[k] + ",");
    }
    return merge;

}
```

Comment: So, what _is_ the problem? You didn't describe it. Where are you stuck?

Comment: FYI, you don't have to put "C#" after your title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for that. It only returns the first value from the List.

Comment: it doesn't look like you ever actually do any comparisons of your int values

Comment: there are other problems as well, but in your 2nd for loop, it should be "j < m.Count", not "j >= m.Count"

Comment: @TheRealBaumann and now I just feel stupid... I was so busy trying to follow the pseudo code I didn't actually stop to think.

Comment: Basically you haven't written the merge part of Mergesort.

Comment: yeah @MrE, I am already hanging my head in shame for it =) But you learn from mistakes so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code (apart from the bug Mike Cowan mentioned) is that you’re not performing any actual sorting. You’re first recursively splitting your lists in half (which is correct), but then you’re simply concatenating them back together in their original order, thereby achieving no result:

```
merge.AddRange(left);
merge.AddRange(right);
```

What you need to do instead is iterate through your two sublists (which, by induction, should have been respectively sorted in the recursive calls), and add elements to the merged list *in order*.

We start off by comparing the 0<sup>th</sup> elements: `left[0]` against `right[0]`. Whichever of the two is smaller, is added to the `merge` list, and its sublist’s counter is incremented. Suppose that `left[0] < right[0]`: we add `left[0]` to `merge`, and in the next iteration, we would then need to consider `left[1]` against `right[0]`. If `left[1]` is again smaller, we add it to `merge` and, in the next iteration, consider `left[2]` against `right[0]`. If `right[0]` is now the smaller of the two, we add *it* to `merge` and, in the next iteration, compare `left[2]` against `right[1]`. And so on.

This keeps going on until one of the sublists is exhausted. When that happens, we simply add all the elements from the remaining sublist into `merge`.

```
int leftIndex = 0;        
int rightIndex = 0;

while (leftIndex < left.Count && rightIndex < right.Count)
    if (left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex])
        merge.Add(left[leftIndex++]);
    else
        merge.Add(right[rightIndex++]);

while (leftIndex < left.Count)
    merge.Add(left[leftIndex++]);
while (rightIndex < right.Count)
    merge.Add(right[rightIndex++]);
```

Additionally, you should not be writing to console *within* your recursive method. Move your `Console.Write` calls to your `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> original = new List<int>(new int[] { 4, 75, 12, 65, 2, 71, 56, 33, 78,1, 4, 56, 85, 12, 5,77, 32, 5 });
    List<int> sorted = mergeSort(original);

    for (int k = 0; k < sorted.Count; k++)
        Console.Write(sorted[k] + ",");
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again. I had to leave it for a while but I got back to it yesterday, fiddled around a bit and got it working (didn't see your edit till now but it makes it that much more clear). I now understand a whole lot more!

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
for (int j = middle; j >= m.Count; j++)
    right.Add(m[j]);
```

should read:

```
for (int j = middle; j < m.Count; j++)
    right.Add(m[j]);
```

Comment: There's of course other problems with the code (i.e., it doesn't sort anything) but it's probably still a work in progress.

Comment: Thank you =) Now it returns but it's nowhere near sorted.

Comment: @JeffMercado it is very much a work in progress, but that tip was a great punt in the right direction =)

Answer (score 4):

First off, the line

```
for (int j = middle; j >= m.Count; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = middle; j < m.Count; j++)
```

Also, you never actually merge the left and right, you're just placing them on top of eachother.  The line

```
merge.AddRange(left);
merge.AddRange(right);
```

Should be something like

```
mergeLeftRight(left, right)
```

Where *mergeLeftRight* is a second function you define that does the actual sorting.  Read the wikipedia article on Merge Sorts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 2):

Simple merge sort steps

1. if( mj.length == 1 ) return mj;
2. Split into left and right lists and recurse
3. when left and right lists return, merge them  **<-- you do not do this**
4. return merged left and right lists